# Creating installer for web apps with visual studio, chrome engine?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, web-applications, microsoft-edge, chromium

Similar to Chrome and Edge, you can install websites as apps through the browser. How can I use something like Visual Studio to create an installer that will similarly install webpages as apps (about 3 at once) BUT use a chromium/chrome/edge web-engine as I believe Visual Studio would by default use the IE Trident engine?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we could try to create a Setup for a Web Application, you could check these links:

[Create Installer (Setup) File for Asp.net Web Application](https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2017/03/create-installer-setup-file-for-aspnet-web-application.html)

[Step by Step Guide to Create a Setup for a Web Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/step-by-step-guide-to-create-a-setup-for-a-web-application/).

To use Edge web engine or Edge-Chromium engine display web page, in my opinion, we could use [WebView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) (EdgeHTML) or [WebView2 control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/gettingstarted) (Edge Chromium)

According to your description, it seems that you want to create an installer or setup, by using it, it will open the Web page using chrome web-engine. If that is the case, I think you could try to create a windows apps and use Webview or Webview2 to display the web page.

Comment: I'm 2 reps behind from 15 so my upvote hasn't shown aha! But this is perfect, I wanted to create 3 web apps based on 3 sites but have one installer install them all running in separate windows but ideally sharing resources to save space

Comment: Here are some resource about creating a Setup Project for multiple applications, you could refer to them: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267236/creating-a-setup-project-for-multiple-applications-in-visual-studio), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer) and [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411249/how-can-i-create-a-setup-file-for-multiple-applications-in-visual-studio).